# Can't bind to 'routerDirection' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: unit-testing, ionic3, ionic4

I have created Application using ionic 4, and I have added routerDirection to my div

```
<div class="finger-print-content" (click)="loginUsingFingerprint()" [routerDirection]="'forward'">
      <img class="fingerprint-btn-img" src="assets/images/fingerprint.png">
      <p class="fingerprint-btn-text" translate>SIGN_IN_USING_FINGERPRINT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

when run`ionic serve` all of things working fine and I serve application in  browser , but when I need to run unit testing `ng test` I see that error.

```
Can't bind to 'routerDirection' since it isn't a known property of 'div'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax should be

```
<div routerLink='/route' routerDirection='forward'>
```

does same as

```
this.navCtlr.goRoot('/route');
```